# Laravel-Mix font path issues

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use a theme which I bought from themeforest with Laravel

I have already use `mix.copy` to move my fonts from `node_modules` to my `public` dir, this works fine./

However when I include the following lines in my `webpack.mix` file,

```
mix.less('node_modules/elite-theme/eliteadmin-dark/less/style.less', 'public/css', './');
```

I get the following errors

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind seems like this is doing the trick

```
mix.options({
  processCssUrls: false
});
```

Set to false to take urls as they are